# Partially displayed UITableViewController like Facebook iphone app

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm searching for the API which propose a tableView partially uncovered, like the one in Facebook app menu. I've seen it in several other apps.

I've heard the Facebook uses the Three20 lib, but this kind of control is not part of their catalog (http://three20.info/). Moreover, three20 seems to be a bit outdated.

If its Three20, which class is it? If no, does it come from an API?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by partially uncovered?

Comment: I mean... this : http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mfsidemenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook does not use Three20 anymore (besides, I strongly discourage its use since it is quite outdated and adds too much dependencies to a project)

Look at third party libraries, there are plenty to do this on Google.

For example, simply on CocoaControls.com you can find [this one](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pprevealsideviewcontroller) or [this one](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mfsidemenu) among others.

[image: PPRevealSideViewController capture]
[image: MFSideMenu sample]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was searching for! +1 for the cocoacontrol.com url